# C++ CUDA Thrust how to make an iterator that contains all even indices then all odd indices?

Tags: c++, cuda, iterator, thrust

For example, if the array has 6 elements, this iterator would like like: `[0, 2, 4, 1, 3, 5]`

I know about `counting_iterator` and `constant_iterator`, but how can I create the above iterator? I think it has something to do with `transform_iterator`, but I don't know how.

Comment: Why do you ask for all odd index then all even index, but are showing all even index then all odd index?

Comment: Can you just use two iterators? One for the even indices and then one for the odd indices?

Comment: @RobertCrovella wording problem. Since the 1st element is 0, it's "odd"

Comment: @talonmies for the thrust::gather function, it only has 1 iterator input (InputIterator map_first and map_last). So I need to make it 1 iterator.

Comment: You can obviously call gather twice too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possible approach. You could use a `permutation_iterator` with a `transform_iterator` inside, something like this:

```
$ cat t87.cu
#include <thrust/iterator/permutation_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/transform_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/counting_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/sequence.h>
#include <thrust/copy.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

struct my_even_odd{
        int s;
        my_even_odd(size_t _s) {s = (_s+1)>>1;}
        __host__ __device__
        int operator()(int i){
                if (i < s) return 2*i;
                return 2*(i-s)+1;}
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  int ds = 7;
  if (argc > 1) ds = atoi(argv[1]);
  thrust::device_vector<int> d(ds);
  thrust::device_vector<int> r(d.size());
  thrust::sequence(d.begin(), d.end());
  thrust::copy_n(thrust::make_permutation_iterator(d.begin(), thrust::make_transform_iterator(thrust::counting_iterator<int>(0), my_even_odd(d.size()))), d.size(), r.begin());
  thrust::host_vector<int> h_r = r;
  thrust::copy(h_r.begin(), h_r.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ","));
  std::cout << std::endl;
}
$ nvcc -o t87 t87.cu
$ ./t87 6
0,2,4,1,3,5,
$ ./t87 7
0,2,4,6,1,3,5,
$
```

I think that should work for even and odd vector sizes, however I have not carefully tested it and make no claims that it is defect-free.

Comment: Is it possible to do this with something simpler, like a transform_iterator ?

Comment: I think what you are asking for is to select first all the even index locations, followed by all the odd index locations.  That is effectively reordering the data array according to an index pattern. That is what a `permutation_iterator` is designed to do, and I have no idea how to do that with a `transform_iterator`, but perhaps you may find a way.

Comment: Well I guess this is the better solution. Thanks!

Comment: I've updated the code with a "simpler" version that moves some of the calculations to the functor instantiation point.